# Blob detection using connected components labelling algorithm

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, blob

I'm trying to write an algorithm to detect blobs using connected component labeling  on an image. I'm having difficulty on how to merge different labels if they are connected diagonally. Doing it for horizontally and vertically connected pixels seems easy . But i can't figure out a way to detect the pixels that are connected diagonally .because if it changes then there is a need to relabel the image w.r.t to that change for each changed pixel . I'm confused . Can you explain me how to handle this. I may be totally wrong about what i said (but i have achieved reasonable results doing only the horizontal and vertical connected components) , but it isn't the correct way. please advice to how to approach connected component labeling accurately. I'm only using arrays of image dimensions for comparing and labelling.

Comment: "But i can't figure out a way to detect the pixels that are connected diagonally .because if it changes then there is a need to relabel the image w.r.t to that change for each changed pixel ."--What do you mean by this?Do you want a way to use diagonal pixels also in your blob?

Comment: two thoughts: (1) please post a portion of your code; (2) if two pixels are "connected" only diagonally, then you're implementing an 8-connected algorithm which may not be what you want. Do you want to detect a checkerboard pattern as a single blob?

Comment: @Rethunk : Hi Rethunk , Thanks for commenting. I was able to solve the problem by noting the equivalences using union-find structure and changing the values of them in the second pass . Now the code works just fine . I used 4-connectivity .

Comment: @Aravind : what i meant was when you are labelling the pixel by comparing its property of interest to its left and top pixels . when the property of interests of both left and top are equal and their labels are unequal. you assign the lower label to the current pixel and after you do that we cant ignore that left and top have same values but different labels. we need to label them again with lowest of both . so i was able to note the equivalency and change them in the next pass. Hope this answers your question. thankyou.

Comment: @chaithu can I see that code? I need to connect two blobs of headlights of cars.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are able to do horizontal and vertical, just add another direction for the diagonal, so you are looking for neighboring pixels in all directions as opposed just to vertical and horizontal.

Comment: Thankyou for answering , I was confused because i couldnt visualize the pixels getting relabelled when it encounters an equivalency w.r.t to its neighbouring pixels . anyway i was able to solve the problem using equivalence class . the algorithm is a two pass